# How many users can I create with useradd without having a visible performace degradation

Tags: performance, users, useradd

Assuming that I have a PC with 2GHz processor, 4GB RAM.

How many users can I create with `useradd` without noticing a visible change in performance in server file operations like (copying files form one user to another, changing owners, etc.) Is is:

- 100
- 1000
- 10000
- ...

Any experience with large number of users?

Comment: *Creating* 1000 users and having them passively exist should not be a problem - user identity is just an ID number and file operations shouldn't care how many users there are. Having 1000 users logged in at once would be a different matter...

Comment: Most of them cannot log in and are just infrastructure user accounts that ensure some security between directories belonging to different applications. The server will run one process (the application) for each of these users. And I assume that our bottleneck in running these application is the first one to hit, not the OS user count problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since about kernel 2.4 linux defines [uid_t as an unsigned int](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/types.h#n31) which gcc compiles as 4 bytes (so the max UID is 4294967296) but you can also have multiple users sharing the same UID (not that it's too practical). But then, as the number of users increase you'll have performance problems with the lookup of users in unsorted flat files (/etc/{passwd,shadow,group}), you should at this point switch to a database (PAM and NSS are the keywords to look for).